# Why an epmd process doesn't exit?

Tags: erlang

Is it a bug or a feature that epmd process still exists after I exit from an erlang shell ?

Comment: You can kill it with `epmd -kill` if you want to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is quite normal: EPMD is a host daemon process. Its presence is required when one intends to use distributed nodes.  It is also useful when just using many nodes on the same machine.

Comment: Although there is no much point of epmd hanging around if no erlang nodes are running :)

Comment: @zed: of course but you probably do not want an Application to carry the burden of managing EPMD's lifecycle :-)

Comment: No need to manage; epmd does know when there are no more VMs there. It could simply kill itself :)

Comment: Why this additional burden? The VMs are quite happy not to have to wait for the services of EPMD to be available.  I don't really see an upside in trying to optimize this situation.

Comment: On my machine epmd is already started by the VM :o) It starts the first time I run `erl` with name or sname.

Comment: @zed: just checked on my machine: epmd is started very early in the boot cycle since I am using lots of erlang based services. I had assumed it was started during boot process independently of VMs but I am proven wrong!