# Something missing in the erlang development workflow

Tags: erlang, rebar

I'm new with erlang and rebar

recently i've readed tutorials about rebar

- [Erlang rebar tutorial](http://www.metabrew.com/article/erlang-rebar-tutorial-generating-releases-upgrades)
- [Erlang application manager with rebar](http://alancastro.org/2010/05/01/erlang-application-management-with-rebar.html)

but i feel something is missing, example after `compile` and `generate` i run my app with the followging command `rel/${nodeid}/bin/${nodeid} console` test code etc. but when i close the console always i need kill my self the `epmd.exe` (from process explorer).

There is some tutorials about more complete for work with rebar?

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2013368/113848).

Answer (score 5):

epmd is the erlang portmapper daemon. It is started automatically if it does not already exist, and the default behavior is to continue running, after any erlang VM stop.

I don't know any option to change this behavior, the command epmd -kill should kill the process as long as no more nodes are registered. you can check it with the command epmd -names

Comment: And this is just exacerbate on Windows, since Windows locks any executables that are running. So in order to generate a new release the epmd process *has* to be killed, otherwise, you can't delete the generated release directory.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving `epmd` running permanently is usually no problem. What is happening here is that the workflow is continually creating epmd.exe, starting it and then trying to delete it - which won't work on Windows.

The easiest workaround I have found is to start `epmd` **outside** of your directory hierarchy, **before** you run rebar. E.g.

```
     "C:\Program Files\erl5.9.3.1\erts-5.9.3.1\bin\epmd"
```

If it is already running then the Erlang runtime won't try to start it from your release folder.